# Arduino multiplication error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Arduino not is able to multiply numbers from 40 onwards by 1000 for example

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    float a = 60 * 1000;
    Serial.print(a);
}
```

the result is -5536 .-. ??? what ??

I need to convert seconds to milliseconds, but I do not know alternatives to multiplication by 1000

Comment: See: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/data-types-in-arduino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are

1. taking a (signed) int and setting it to 60
2. taking a (signed) int and setting it to 1000
3. multiplying them, obtaining a signed int. This generates an overflow, so the result is -5536
4. converting this number in a float; -5536 -> -5536.0

The solution? Since you want to deal with floats... Operate with floats!

```
float a = ((float)60) * 1000;
float a = 60.0 * 1000;
```

The two solutions are the same; the first converts (int)60 in a float, then multiplies it by (int)1000, which gives you (float)60000.
The second tells the compiler that 60.0 is a float.

In both cases a float multiplied by an int gives you a float, so... No overflow!

Comment: Ahh yes, it is easy to forget that integer constants are 16 bit signed by default: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntegerConstants

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Serial.print` converts `a` to signed integer. Try this:

```
Serial.print((float)a);
```

or this:

```
#include "floatToString.h"
char buffer[25];
Serial.print(floatToString(buffer, a, 5));
```